# Maintained UPnP server on 13.04?

Tags: server, 13.04, dlna, upnp, mediatomb

I'm looking to create a UPnP server on my 13.04 server installation. I've done some searching and installing but nothing seems to fit the criteria for me.

I'm just wondering if there are any still maintained UPnP servers for 13.04?

I've been playing with Mediatomb, but it doesn't organize my files correctly, even after linking to import scripts. Furthermore, it doesn't appear to be maintained anymore, as the most recent release is still from quite a while ago, though I may be wrong.

PS3 Media Server doesn't seem to work with a variety of devices either.

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of problems with each different dlna/upnp media server option. It's simply a matter of choosing which compromise works best for you. On a workstation type system, where you're running Unity or GNOME, and logged in all the time, and want to run a media server as the user you're logged in as, I would highly recommend `rygel`, as it works quite well, supports a wide variety of formats, uses standard infrastructure such as GStreamer and tracker, and can transcode on the fly. I have been using it for several years now.

However, it does require a DBus session bus, and X11 display, which presents a bit of a problem when running on a headless server system. I recently migrated all my Music and Video files over to my local server, which has a huge RAID setup, and runs Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS, and is of course, headless. Unfortunately, `rygel` wasn't usable there, so I had to find something else. I am running `minidlna` as the media server there, and it is working quite well. It is maintained (there's a newer version in 13.04), but not without its own set of flaws. I would recommend it for a headless server, though. It's very simple to set up, and even runs as a system service, just like `apache` or `dnsmasq`. Just remember to make sure all the files and directories you're pointing it at, are readable by the `minidlna` user, or everyone, before you start it. It doesn't take too long for it to scan the files, and it's very easy to blow away the database cache it creates, and restart the service, to force a rescan.

Comment: If you install rygel, install rygel-preferences as well (GUI to rygel config)

Answer (score 0):

As I ran into trouble with miniDLNA (e.g. my Samsung TV failed to play videos), I decided to try out *Serviio*. It worked out-of-the-box, and my UE55ES plays videos fine even using the Generic profile (*Serviio* offers different profiles for problematic clients). Video files needed some naming tricks for metadata to be collected, but that was all to do (except for downloading static FFMPeg binaries optionally). For details, see my answer to [minidlna and samsung tv file format doesn't support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313275/68291), which also mentions a few more alternatives.